# How should I use this Github project properly?

Tags: swift, xcode, github

I’m trying to use Cards from github ,
Link [here](https://github.com/PaoloCuscela/Cards/wiki/Overview)

But when I try `card.detailView = detailVC1?.view`, it gives me an error:

> Value of type CardHighlight has no member detailView

detailVC1 is: `let detailVC1 = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CardContent")`

What should I do ?

Comment: Can you add more information on how you initialized your detailVC?

Comment: try card.detailView = detailVC?

Comment: Are you creating the `card` from storyboard or by code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`detailView` is a **private/fileprivate**  property of the `ViewController` managed by the `Card` class.
Both are not accessible directly anyway, you should use `card.shouldPresent(.class, from: self)`
to set you view controller.

**For example:**

```
let detailVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CardContent")

card.shouldPresent(detailVC, from: self)
```